# MonoPosixHelper-x86_64.dll - ClamAV detects this as a threat/infection

Tags: mono

Can anyone from the mono project team confirm that the file `MonoPosixHelper-x86_64.dll` is not malicious? ClamAV detects it as a threat. It is found under the `/mono_2.0/bin` folder under `/.wine` on Linux. The file exists even when wine is reinstalled.

By the way, it's only ClamAV which detects this, according to virustotal.com

Comment: I think that this question is a [bit off-topic on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You can try asking on [one of affiliated sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: Yes, it might be. I am just trying to get in contact with anyone from the mono project as this file seems to be related to it.